# Improve speed of appending array elements if not already in array

Tags: matlab, performance, vectorization, union

I have an array `S`, which has some number of unique elements. I want to append elements from array `N` which are not already in `S`.

A syntactically simple way to do this would be:

```
S = union( S, N, 'stable' );
```

I found manually appending could be quicker, using `ismember` or implicit expansion:

```
% ismember approach
S = [S; N(~ismember(N,S))];
% imp. expansion approach
S = [S; N(~any(S(:)==N(:).',1))];
```

However, this still feels pretty dirty to do inside a loop, and the implicit expansion can be expensive for large inputs.

Is there a more performant alternative?

If it helps, we can assume `S` and `N` contain only integers. However, we can't assume that `S` is sorted, new elements appended from `N` could be any positive integer.

Minimal example:

```
Ntest = [1 2 3 4
         2 5 3 6
         1 5 7 9];
S = [];
for ii = 1:3
    N = Ntest(ii,:).';
    S = union(S,N,'stable');
end
% S = [ 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 9 ]
```

In the real case, I don't know the potential values of `N` up front like I did with `Ntest` above.

Here is some benchmarking code for 4 methods, with the following results. In my case, it's likely that I'll have a large loop for different values of `N`, and a small number of elements in each `N`. This corresponds to the right-most columns in this summary table, where you can see the implicit expansion method is much quicker.

```
range(Ntest): 1 to 1e4     1 to 1e4     1 to 1e4    1 to 1e4
size(Ntest):  [1e3,1e3]    [1e4,1e3]    [1e2,1e3]   [1e2,1e4]
union:        0.972 sec    1.217 sec    0.779 sec   9.341 sec
ismember:     0.763 sec    0.559 sec    0.492 sec   5.439 sec
implicit:     6.966 sec    too long!    0.295 sec   3.886 sec
setdiff:      0.599 sec    0.534 sec    0.477 sec   5.364 sec
```

```
rng(0);
Ntest = randi([1,1e4],1e3,1e3);

f = @()f_union( Ntest );
fprintf( 'union: \t%.3f sec\n', timeit( f ) );
f = @()f_ismember( Ntest );
fprintf( 'ismember: \t%.3f sec\n', timeit( f ) );
f = @()f_implicit( Ntest );
fprintf( 'implicit: \t%.3f sec\n', timeit( f ) );
f = @()f_setdiff( Ntest );
fprintf( 'setdiff: \t%.3f sec\n', timeit( f ) );

function f_union( Ntest )
    S = [];
    for ii = 1:size(Ntest,2)
        N = Ntest(:,ii);
        S = union(S,N,'stable');
    end
end
function f_ismember( Ntest )
    S = [];
    for ii = 1:size(Ntest,2)
        N = Ntest(:,ii);
        S = [S; N(~ismember(N,S))];
    end    
end
function f_implicit( Ntest )
    S = [];
    for ii = 1:size(Ntest,2)
        N = Ntest(:,ii);
        S = [S; N(~any(S(:)==N(:).',1))];
    end    
end
function f_setdiff( Ntest )    
    S = [];
    for ii = 1:size(Ntest,2)
        N = Ntest(:,ii);
        S = [S;setdiff(N,S)];
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is assumed that the data type is positive integer you can use logical matrix to store position of integers:

```
function f_logical( Ntest )
    S = false;
    for ii = 1:size(Ntest,2)
        N = Ntest(:,ii);
        S(N) = true;
    end    
end
```

If the range of elements is large and the data has sparsity it may be beneficial to use sparse matrix:

```
function f_sparse( Ntest )
    S = sparse(false);
    for ii = 1:size(Ntest,2)
        N = Ntest(:,ii);
        S(N) = true;
    end    
end
```

Comparing with the `ismember` solution in Octave:

```
Elapsed time for <ismember> is 1.54181 seconds.
Elapsed time for <sparse>   is 0.266474 seconds.
Elapsed time for <logical>  is 0.0189412 seconds.
```

Comment: This I a great perspective shift, thanks for the idea! I will try it out as soon as I'm back in the office

Comment: This clearly saved a small amount of time for my wider algorithm's test cases. I was still surprised to then see it saved **~90%** of the processing time for large runs on my real data! I can handle the non-sparse arrays too, but thanks for the extra consideration.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Thanks for bounty!

Answer (score 3):

I guess you can use the following code to speed up

```
X = setdiff(N,S);
S(end + (1:length(X))) = X;
```

- **Remarks**
  `X = N(~ismember(N,S))` and `X = setdiff(N,S)` are both fine to find the elements that in `N` but not in `S`, but the key step for speeding up the appending process is the following way

```
S(end + (1:length(X))) = X;
```

- **Performance Comparison**

```
rng(0);
Ntest = randi([1,1e4],1e4,1e4);

f = @()f_union( Ntest );
fprintf( 'union: \t%.3f sec\n', timeit( f ) );
f = @()f_ismember_v1( Ntest );
fprintf( 'ismember_v1: \t%.3f sec\n', timeit( f ) );
f = @()f_ismember_v2( Ntest );
fprintf( 'ismember_v2: \t%.3f sec\n', timeit( f ) );
f = @()f_setdiff_v1( Ntest );
fprintf( 'setdiff_v1: \t%.3f sec\n', timeit( f ) );
f = @()f_setdiff_v2( Ntest );
fprintf( 'setdiff_v2: \t%.3f sec\n', timeit( f ) );

function f_union( Ntest )
    S = [];
    for ii = 1:size(Ntest,2)
        N = Ntest(:,ii);
        S = union(S,N,'stable');
    end
end

function f_ismember_v1( Ntest )
    S = [];
    for ii = 1:size(Ntest,2)
        N = Ntest(:,ii);
        S = [S; N(~ismember(N,S))];
    end    
end

function f_ismember_v2( Ntest )
    S = [];
    for ii = 1:size(Ntest,2)
        N = Ntest(:,ii);
        X = N(~ismember(N,S));
        S(end + (1:length(X))) = X;
    end    
end

function f_setdiff_v1( Ntest )    
    S = [];
    for ii = 1:size(Ntest,2)
        N = Ntest(:,ii);
        S = [S;setdiff(N,S)];
    end
end

function f_setdiff_v2( Ntest )    
    S = [];
    for ii = 1:size(Ntest,2)
        N = Ntest(:,ii);
        X = setdiff(N,S);
        S(end + (1:length(X))) = X;
    end
end
```

giving

```
union:  13.314 sec
ismember_v1:    5.836 sec
ismember_v2:    5.658 sec
setdiff_v1:     4.371 sec
setdiff_v2:     4.248 sec
```

Comment: Yep sorry, omitted from my question, this is slower for me than the `ismember` approach for determining the set difference, perhaps surprisingly.

Comment: @Wolfie yes, you are right, I guess `ismember` is the fastest so far among the three approaches i added in my answer, but has only tiny advantage than `setdiff` approach

Comment: @Wolfie I updated my solution, which now is much faster than `ismember` approach

Comment: What if you do `X=  N(~ismember(N,S))` and then append as you do with the `setdiff` method?

Comment: Thanks, I've added a benchmark to my question which might help you test this against my other options

Comment: Note that `tic/toc` is not recommended for accurate timing. Rather use [`timeit()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html), which overcomes most limitations of a simple `tic/toc`. `tic/toc` should only be used for rough order-of-magnitude comparisons.

Comment: @CrisLuengo then it would be a bit faster than `setdiff` ....so maybe we can say that  `ismember` should be the most efficient one?

Comment: @Wolfie thanks for your benchmark template, I tried to run with different approaches and their variants, you can see the performance difference now... but I guess the speed may also be depending on the sizes of `Ntest`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding thanks, yes in writing the benchmark I realised how dependent on the input size this problem is, which I didn't appreciate fully before. I'll test on my real data this afternoon, your appending method is likely an improvement

Comment: @Wolfie Yes, I think the major improvements comes from using `S(end + (1:length(X))) = X`. Good luck to your test!

Comment: That appending saves me ~18% on processing time, which is great! I'll hold out for any more answers as that doesn't actually address the union operation, and accept this if none come :)